# ASP.NET IAuthorizationFilter OnAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

Hi I am trying to implement a custom Authorization filter

```
 //The Authourization attribute on a controller
public class CustomAdminAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthentication _authentication;

    public SageAdminAuthorizationFilter(IAuthentication authentication)
    {
        _authentication = authentication;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       bool result = _authentication.Authorize(filterContext.HttpContext);
    }
}
```

As you can see on the OnAuthorization I get back a result that is true of false.
What do I need to set to return where I came from?

EDIT:

It still seems to throw me straight to the log in page

I do inject IAuthetication

```
 this.BindFilter<CustomAdminAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0);
   Bind<IAuthentication>().To<CustomAuthenticationService>();
```

Then I decorate my action in the controller as so.

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
```

In my web.config Im using

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Should this be altered?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change that to an `Attribute`, not simple a `IAuthorizationFilter`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SageAdminAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly IAuthentication _authentication;

    public SageAdminAuthorizeAttribute(IAuthentication authentication)
    {
        _authentication = authentication;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!_authentication.Authorize(filterContext.HttpContext))
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

And now rather than using `[Authorize]` use your new `[SageAdminAuthorize]` attribute

```
[SageAdminAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that sort of answer my question although I have added more details because I am always going to the log on screen

Comment: I used the example above to create a new attribute called 'Permission'.  I wanted to use permission based authorization instead of roles.  Is that the correct way?  Or should I be using some other way to check for user permissions?

Comment: Definitely a good way to go. You can determine how Authorization is handled in your `OnAuthorization` method any way you choose.

Comment: Base interface `IAuthorizationFilter` is redundant because `AuthorizeAttribute` already implements it.

Comment: Also, the AttributeUsageAttribute is redundant because it is inherited from its parent.  OnAuthorization should also be implemented using the override keyword.  The base class implements the interface, you're just modifying its behavior.

Comment: This doesn't work because the attribute itself has a constructor that requires arguments. How do we set up the attribute to work without explicit arguments (and instead delegate those to DI to fulfill)?