# How to authenticate a user with a password and another field in an ASP.Net MVC3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm currently developping an ASP.Net MVC3 application, and I have created a Custom Membership Provider that extends the Membership Provider.

This works fine, but my problem is for exemple I need a method like

```
Membership.ValidateUser(username, password, passkey)
```

How can I do this? An IIS module is the way to go? Web.Config configuration?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: We don't delete questions because the answers may be too complicated. The answers might help someone else out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `ActionFilter` which derives from [IAuthorizationFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx) Interface. See an example of that:

[ASP.NET IAuthorizationFilter OnAuthorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663405/asp-net-iauthorizationfilter-onauthorization)

Comment: How can this create a method ValidateUser with 3 parameters?

Comment: @Swell You need to provide the logic yourself. You asked this: ***how can I do this? An IIS module is the way to go? Web.Config configuration?*** This is where you do it.

Comment: Maybe my question was not that clear, my problem came from the base type of the System.Web.Security.Membership. Is there a way to change it to something else?

Comment: @Swell MembershipApi methods make database calls to you membership database in order to authenticate a user. You can do the same.

Comment: Tugberk, thanks for your answers, but it seems my problem is not easy to solve with my current knowledge of ASP.Net. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom MembershipProvider that accepts 3 parameters to validate the user.

Comment: Thanks Duy, but what I want to do is in fact quite more complex :( I need to learn more on ASP.Net & ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: @Swell: this is actually quite simple to do, once you've got the hang of it. As I said above, you need to implement your own Membership Provider, in which there would be a validate method that accepts 3 parameters, within this method, you do your credential check. Now this could be against a SQL database, Active Directory or any other back end system (in fact I've done something quite similar to yours that validate the user thru a Java web services), if the credentials are valid, you will then validate the auth ticket (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) Lemme know if you need an example

Comment: In my ASP.Net MVC application the Membership is a System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider type. My own provider inherits from this type and even if I create a validate method with 3 parameters, I can't see it, since the Membership member is not of my own type.