# Array usage in the System.Web.Http.Authorize

Tags: c#

I am wondering instead of fixing roles string

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles ="Admin,UlooDaPahta,ChawalManager," )]
```

Can we use string/Array in of roles?

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles =MyStr)]

[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles =MyArray)]
```

thanks

Comment: Sure, as long as it's a `const`.

Comment: Attribute parameters are evaluated at compile time, so the answer is no.

Comment: but roles are dynamic, new roles shall be added into database.

Comment: You could build your own Authorization filter that takes a array as a argument. Just look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663405/asp-net-iauthorizationfilter-onauthorization