# How "Don't Repeat Yourself" in methods of a Controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop

within each methods of a controller , I have to execute a method.

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    if (Foo(id, SessionManage.DataSession) )
        return RedirectToAction("Page1");

    Code4Index1();
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    if (Foo(id, SessionManage.DataSession) )
        return RedirectToAction("Page1");

    Code4Index2();
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Index3()
{
    if (Foo(id, SessionManage.DataSession) )
        return RedirectToAction("Page1");

    Code4Index3();
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Index4()
{
    if (Foo(id, SessionManage.DataSession) )
        return RedirectToAction("Page1");

    Code4Index4();
    return View();
}
```

Is there a smarter way than organize the code or I am forced to go against DRY concept?
I'd like not repeat the code for each method :

```
 if (Foo(id, SessionManage.DataSession) )
    return RedirectToAction("Page1");
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Where is `id` coming from? What you need is a custom [ActionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Why do you have so many *Index* methods in the first place if they all check and return the same thing? That is redundant within itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ASPNET has already the infrastructure for handling authorization so why not just use it?

- Create a new attribute class, inherited from AuthorizeAttribute
- Override the methods:

  - OnAuthorization:  to perform your check
  - HandleUnauthorizedRequest:  to decide whats the result view that the user will see.
- Mark your controller methods with this attribute.

Your attribute may look like:

```
class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        // Do whatever you want here, for example
        //filterContext.Result = new whatever() ;

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if ( /* the request does not pass your checks */ )
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
}
```

And your controller code will look like:

```
[MyCustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    return View();
}

[MyCustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index2()
{
   return View();
}

[MyCustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index3()
{    
    return View();
}

[MyCustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index4()
{    
    return View();
}
```

You can also check this post for a more clear example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663518/1413973

Comment: you do not worry permissions ... I changed the question! Thanks

Comment: The procedure is just about the same. Just create a custom action filter and override "OnActionExecuting"... Done

Answer (score 1):

You can **refactor** your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    return AccessDeniedRedirect();
}

public ActionResult Index2()
{
    return AccessDeniedRedirect();
}

public ActionResult Index3()
{
    return AccessDeniedRedirect();
}

public ActionResult Index4()
{
    return AccessDeniedRedirect();
}

private ActionResult AccessDeniedRedirect()
{
    if (Checks(id, SessionManage.DataSession))
        return RedirectToAction("AccesDiened");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: That's _still_ repeating yourself.

Comment: If he *really* need that many Index's or not is a question mark for me too.

Comment: No, I meant copying the method call itself. That is not the idiomatic way to do this in MVC, it's an ActionFilter.

Comment: Ahh I got it, you're right. Creating a custom ActionFilter is a better solution in MVC. But OP's controller code has some structural problems which are easier to solve in routing level.